LinkedIn API (OAUTH 2.0)
In order to login with linkedIn and retrieve some info of the user logged, i used this code in my NodeJS / ExpressJS application.
I'm having trouble requesting an access token on the linkedIn developer platform. I'm receiving this error,
"Oops. We can’t verify the authenticity of your request because the state parameter was modified."
And I'm receiving this error on the browser when i successfully enter my login identifiers:
InternalOAuthError: failed to fetch user profile
    at Strategy.<anonymous> (H:\My Projects\linkedAuth\node_modules\passport-linkedin-oauth2\lib\oauth2.js:57:19)
    at passBackControl (H:\My Projects\linkedAuth\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:132:9)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (H:\My Projects\linkedAuth\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:157:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:530:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1696:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)

I expect to retrieve the data of the user logged in order to insert it into my local database, and then later post a publication in the user's linkedIn feed
This is the app.js file:
const http = require("http");
const express = require("express");
const { join } = require("path");
const session = require("express-session");
const MySQLStore = require("express-mysql-session")(session);
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const db = require("./db");
const logger = require("./logger");
const { dbConfig } = require("./config");
const { linkedInConfig } = require("./linkedIn");
const passport = require("passport");
const LinkedInStrategy = require("passport-linkedin-oauth2").Strategy;

const app = express();
const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
const base_url = join(__dirname, "/");

const sessionStore = new MySQLStore(dbConfig);

app.use(logger.apiLogger);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(join(__dirname, "public")));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(
  session({
    secret: "mysecret",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: sessionStore,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, // 30 jours
      secure: false,
      httpOnly: true,
    },
  })
);

passport.use(
  new LinkedInStrategy(
    {
      clientID: linkedInConfig.clientID,
      clientSecret: linkedInConfig.clientSecret,
      callbackURL: "http://localhost:3009/auth/linkedin/callback",
      scope: ["w_member_social", "openid", "email", "profile"],
      state: true,
    },
    function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      console.log("Fetching LinkedIn profile...");

      this._oauth2.get("https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me", accessToken, function (err, body, res) {
        if (err) {
          console.error("Failed to fetch user profile:", err);
          return done(new InternalOAuthError("failed to fetch user profile", err));
        }

        try {
          console.log("LinkedIn profile data:", body);
          const json = JSON.parse(body);
          const userProfile = {
            id: json.id,
            firstName: json.localizedFirstName,
            lastName: json.localizedLastName,
            profilePicture: json.profilePicture["displayImage~"].elements[0].identifiers[0].identifier,
            accessToken: accessToken,
          };
          return done(null, userProfile);
        } catch (e) {
          console.error("Failed to parse LinkedIn profile:", e);
          return done(e);
        }
      });
    }
  )
);

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser((obj, done) => {
  done(null, obj);
});

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.get(
  "/auth/linkedin",
  (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("Redirecting to LinkedIn for authentication");
    next();
  },
  passport.authenticate("linkedin", { state: true })
);

app.get(
  "/auth/linkedin/callback",
  (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("Callback URL hit");
    console.log("State parameter:", req.query.state);
    next();
  },
  passport.authenticate("linkedin", { failureRedirect: "/error" }),
  function (req, res) {
    console.log("Authentication successful:", req.user);
    res.redirect("/");
  }
);

app.get("/error", (req, res) => {
  console.error("Authentication failed");
  res.send("Désolé, une erreur s’est produite. Dans 5 secondes, vous serez redirigé(e) vers : localhost");
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(base_url + "public/auth.html");
});

let port = 3009;
httpServer.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`\x1b[32m[APP] Server running on\x1b[97m\x1b[1m http://localhost:${port}\x1b[0m`);
});


state: true is suspicious. Shouldn't it be a random string?

The state value should be a randomly generated string, it is a way of countering CSRF attacks.
Here is a sample Js function that generates a random string
    const generateRandomString = (length = 20) => {
    let result = ''
    const characters =
        'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'
    const charactersLength = characters.length
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        result += characters.charAt(
            Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength)
        )
    }
    return result
}

Here how my getUrl function looks like:
const getUrl = () => {
    const scopeParam = `&scope=${encodeURI(scope)}`
    const generatedState = state || generateRandomString()
    localStorage.setItem(LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_STATE, generatedState)
    const linkedInAuthLink = `https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}${scopeParam}&state=${generatedState}`
    return linkedInAuthLink
}

So this getUrl function generates the linked auth url and sets the state as the random string.
Note: you should somehow store this state so you can cross-check with the response from linkedin to ensure its the same
